# Caching or Core Data for semi-perminant image and video persistence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, core-data, video

(Note there is a TLDR at the bottom if this is a lot of text)

I'm working on something that pulls and displays images and videos from a server. Essentially think of different folders with pictures and videos behind them that you can view.

Each folder gets updated with new pictures and videos fairly consistently, so I would like to be able to store as many of these pictures and videos at a time to minimize loading/requesting-from-database time by preloading and saving a few.

**Let me preface all this by saying I can very well be completely wrong about anything I write following this line. Which is why I'm asking. I'm not 100% clear on the capabilities of each approach**

I'm going to try to be as organized as possible here:

Reqs/Usage:

- Save large files (image and video data) for quick access (populated from Server)
- Quick rotation on saved data; constantly updated
- Files are definitely transient, I don't want to show expired information but I don't want to keep reloading similar stuff every time I need to see it.
- Needs to be able to full store multiple folders worth of data, say 8-12MB worth of files per folder on the mid-high range (not very useful if only one is instantly accessible and rest still have to be loaded from database when viewed)
- Efficient network usage (avoid redundant calls to fully repopulate table every time)
- Persist across app backgrounds / store new data indefinitely until enough internet to upload
- There is a notable one-to-many relationship of folder to files within that folder... I need to be able to access all files within a folder easily
- (easier to code/maintain... not necessary but would be nice)

My rational for **Core Data**:

PROS:

- Supports most of what I want to do by default
- Save all other aspects of my model objects that aren't large media files with ease (ex. name of folder, etc) in an easily query-able way
- Lots of great tools like [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) to interact with server/make it easy
- Potential to store more data at a time by saving to file system
- Easy to persist

CONS:

- This isn't the typical Core Data set-up because I'm not particularly concerned with permanent storage, I just want as many folders as possible to be instantly available; clearing memory as needed.
- **SPEED**: Minor edits still require entire context to be re-saved. Meaning it's slower to load, sync, and flush than caching (see [this](http://biasedbit.com/filesystem-vs-coredata-image-cache/) for actual speed metrics... its definitely not nontrivial). Lots of continual writing to disk seems like it could be problematic in terms of performance.

Rational for **Caching**:

PROS:

- **QUICKER**: More in line with the semi-perminant aspect (quick rotation of saved data, etc)
- Easier memory management (won't have to be continually and manually clearing out old data that's been saved to Core Data that I no longer need/want)
- Less boilerplate/quantity of code

CONS:

- doesn't persist by default, clears on background
- less memory to work with; really concerned about performance issues of having to delete and reload data into memory constantly.
- no querying support and (I don't think) no way of selectively clearing certain properties of objects while keeping other properties (I think you'd have to decode entire object, clear some info manually, and re-encode?)
- clears when app backgrounds by default (i.e less control over when information is dumped to free up memory that may be needed)

### **TLDR**

Should I use caching or Core Data to save large files that are going to be updated from a server semi-frequently? The factors to consider for me are **efficiency** (minimize server requests; store data until it's overwritten with new data), **speed** (to write/load), **amount of data stored/memory available** (memory concerns with moving large amounts of data using caching, will it affect performance.. how many files can I have in memory at once before I start to see adverse performance?), **customizability** (it seems to me like i need something in between the two, so which is easier to adapt to my uses)

and importantly.... is there something else I'm missing completely? Like some sort of file system manager or unique caching ma-jiggy?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is caching files, then there is not much need for CoreData, as the file system itself is a really fast key/value store for files.

If you want to have a bunch of associated data for the files, you can set extended attributes on the files (though you can't efficiently use those attributes in a search).

If you still want to use CoreData, you can certainly do so.  You have several options.  The most common two options are:

1. Store the file's URL as an attribute in the CoreData entity, and manage storing the files directly to disk yourself.
2. Store the data as a CoreData attribute, and select the "Allows External Storage" option for the attribute.  This will cause CoreData to do its own calculation, and if the data is "small enough" it will be stored in the database.  If it is "too large" then it will be stored as an external file.

Apple does not document the cutoff value, but experimentation has shown it to be 1MB.

It is much easier to go with option 2, as Core Data will manage it all for you.  This is a very viable option, and I have used it in one really large application that stores a bunch of really large files (none are small enough to be selected to live in the database).

There are issues with migration speed, because Core Data wants to migrate the entire store.  Thus, you will want to take that into consideration before deciding.

You may want to build a test app, and add a bunch of stuff, and go through various scenarios before deciding, but those are the two most common options available to you.